# How to vertically align and stretch subchild of flexbox element?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm currently trying to build a mobile nav with Flexbox :
A vertical menu that take 100% of the available height. The nav items are evenly placed and takes the whole height.

I use a `ul>li>a` structure.

[image: what the menu should look like]

### The issue :

I can't find a way to:

1. force `<a>` to take 100% of the parent `li` height
2. make the content of `a` vertically align.

I did success to do one or the other, but seems I can't have both :(

Here a jsFiddle of what I got so far :
http://jsfiddle.net/hopxzcq3/

```
<nav>
   <ul class="main-nav">
        <li><a href="#">Cat 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Cat 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Cat 3</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Cat 4</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Cat 5</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>

.main-nav {
    display:flex;
    flex-direction:column;
    justify-content:space-between;
    height:100%;
}
.main-nav li {
    display:flex;
    flex-grow: 1;
}
.main-nav li a {
    display:block;
    width:100%; height:100%;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `flex:1` on the anchor instead of `display:block; width:100%; height:100%;`

```
.main-nav li a 
{ 
    flex:1; /* make the anchor full size*/

    display:flex;  /*these 2 are needed for vertical alignment*/
    align-items: center;
}
```

[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/peteng/hopxzcq3/3/)

Comment: Hi. This is not exactly what I asked. The `a` do take 100% of the height but the content isn't verticallty align.

Comment: @saawsann see edit - I missed that bit somehow (too late on a friday!)

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I need.